# How to make a longtable has rounded corners?

Tags: tables, pdftex, longtable

I try this, but it does not work

```
\begin{table}
\caption{A table with rounded corners}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table) [inner sep=0pt] {
  \begin{longtable}{l|l}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Team sheet} \\
    \hline
    GK & Paul Robinson \\
    LB & Lucus Radebe \\
    DC & Michael Duberry \\
    DC & Dominic Matteo \\
    RB & Didier Domi \\
    MC & David Batty \\
    MC & Eirik Bakke \\
    MC & Jody Morris \\
    FW & Jamie McMaster \\
    ST & Alan Smith \\
    ST & Mark Viduka \\
  \end{longtable}
};
\draw [rounded corners=.5em] (table.north west) rectangle (table.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please make your example compilable?

Comment: both `table` and `tikzpicture` make unbreakable tex boxes that can not break over a page, and you have `longtable` inside _both_ of them? Do you need page breaking? If not then you do not need longtable at all, just use `tabular`

Comment: It's just an example, I use the longtable for tables that span multiple pages, but need to be rounded corners

Comment: @IvnAquino,  `longtable` should not be inside float `table`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you like to obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1mm,
               preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table with rounded corners}
    \centering
\tcbox[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm,
       boxrule=0.4pt, colback=white]% set to your wish
    {\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Team sheet} \\
    \hline% if you liked
GK & Paul Robinson \\
LB & Lucus Radebe \\
DC & Michael Duberry \\
DC & Dominic Matteo \\
RB & Didier Domi \\
MC & David Batty \\
MC & Eirik Bakke \\
MC & Jody Morris \\
FW & Jamie McMaster \\
ST & Alan Smith \\
ST & Mark Viduka 
    \end{tabular}}
    \label{tab1}
\end{table}        
    \end{document}
```

**Edit/Upgrade:**
For use of longtable ... you need `tcolorbox` width option `breakable` and some manual tweak for adjusting box width or use some other tabular environment, something like `xtab`, which mimic `tabularx`accommodation to given box width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

    \centering
\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw,% if you like to have rounded corners 
                        % on each end/beginning of table, 
                        % than remove this option
        breakable,
        left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm,
        boxrule=0.4pt, colback=white}% set to your wish

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4.05cm]% width determined "experimentally"
    \begin{longtable}{l|l}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Team sheet} \\
    \hline% if you liked
GK & Paul Robinson \\
LB & Lucus Radebe \\
DC & Michael Duberry \\
DC & Dominic Matteo \\
RB & Didier Domi \\
MC & David Batty \\
MC & Eirik Bakke \\
MC & Jody Morris \\
FW & Jamie McMaster \\
ST & Alan Smith \\
ST & Mark Viduka
    \end{longtable}
\end{tcolorbox}
    \end{document}
```

This code gives:

[image]

I didn't bother with caption issues. It can be done within `longtable` or within `tcolorbox`. For latter see tcolorbox manual, chapter Library "breakable!, pp. 304. Deficiency of above solution is manually adjusting of tcolorbox width, however, as I already mentioned, with use some other tabular environment, this can be easily solved

Comment: Yes but I wanted a longtable for use with tables that span several pages

Comment: Then first provide an MWE with long table, I'm now occupied with some work and haven't time to make an example of `longtable` for you. `tcolorbox` has option `breakable` so this should work. Read comments above.

Comment: @IvnAquino, I was to optimistic, that `longtable` can be nested in some other environment. The solution as I see now is  manually dividing `longtable` in several tabulars. Or wait if somebody know better solution.